# Why rsyslog logs the same log multiple times

Tags: c, server, daemon, rsyslog

**SOLVED: Changed c == accept(... to c = accept(...
One should use -Wall to see warning when == is used improperly.**

I configure syslog connection opening

```
openlog("program", LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
```

Server code:

```
for (;;) {
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "before accept");
    if ((c == accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &b)) == -1) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "could not accept on socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "after accept");
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "could not fork to handle client session");
        exit(1);
    } else if (0 == pid) {
        close(s);
        handle_client(c);
        exit(0);
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "exit after");
    } else
        close(c);
}
```

Then I conenct using telnet

```
telnet localhost 2345
...
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Log */var/log/user.log* shows

```
...some_info...: client was handled
...some_info...: client was handled
...some_info...: before accept
...some_info...: after accept
...some_info...: before accept
...some_info...: after accept
...some_info...: client was handled
```

It looks like that rsyslog logged message multiple times in random order,
although I know that I called telnet only once.
I clearly understand how the program executed, but do not understand why rsyslog logged multiples times.

Could you please suggest how to fix that "bug"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one bug:

```
if ((c == accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &b)) == -1) {
```

where `c` will never equal `-1`. It should be

```
if ((c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &b)) == -1) {
```

**Edit**

This will have a knock-on effect to the subsequent code using `c`, which can only have the values `0` or `1`.

```
handle_client(c);
```

and

```
close(c);
```